# Ember simple auth with custom server authentication (credentials undefined)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am newbie with Ember and trying to implement a basic auth (username + password in the 'authentication' header) with a **custom server** using ember simple auth and ember-cli. The problem is that the **credentials object is undefined** when it is received within the '**authenticate**' method defined in the **CustomAuthenticator**.

What's wrong with this code?

***app/initializers/login.js***

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import BaseAuthenticator from 'simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import BaseAuthorizer from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';

window.ENV = window.ENV || {};
window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'authorizer:custom',
    session: 'session:withCurrentUser'
};

export default {
    name: 'authentication',
    before: 'simple-auth',
    initialize: function(container/*, application*/) {
        container.register('authorizer:custom', CustomAuthorizer);
        container.register('authenticator:custom', CustomAuthenticator);
    }
};

var CustomAuthorizer = BaseAuthorizer.extend({
    authorize: function(jqXHR/*, requestOptions*/) {
        if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('session.token'))) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token: ' + this.get('session.token'));
        }
    }
});

var CustomAuthenticator = BaseAuthenticator.extend({

    tokenEndpoint: '/v1/login',

     restore: function(data) {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (!Ember.isEmpty(data.token)) {
          resolve(data);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    },
    authenticate: function(credentials) {
        //*** HERE THE CREDENTIALS OBJECT IS NULL ***
        var _this = this;
        if(!Ember.isEmpty(credentials.identification)) {                               
           return this._super(credentials); 
        } else {
            return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                Ember.$.ajax({
                    url:         _this.tokenEndpoint,
                    type:        'POST',
                    data:        JSON.stringify({ session: { identification: credentials.identification, password: credentials.password } }),
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    Ember.run(function() {
                        resolve({ token: response.session.token });
                    });
                }, function(xhr/*, status, error*/) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    Ember.run(function() {
                        reject(response.error);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    },
    invalidate: function() {
      var _this = this;
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        Ember.$.ajax({ url: _this.tokenEndpoint, type: 'DELETE' }).always(function() {
          resolve();
        });
      });
    },
});
```

***app/pods/login/controller.js***

```
import AuthenticationControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authentication-controller-mixin';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(AuthenticationControllerMixin, {
    authenticator: 'authenticator:custom'
});
```

***app/pods/login/template.hbs***

```
<div class='container'>

    <form {{action 'authenticate' on='submit'}}>
        <label for="identification">Login</label>
        {{input value=identification placeholder='Enter Login'}}
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        {{input value=password placeholder='Enter Password' type='password'}}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    {{#if errorMessage}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <p>
            <strong>Login failed:</strong> <code>{{errorMessage}}</code>
          </p>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import LoginControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/login-controller-mixin';`

instead of

`import AuthenticationControllerMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authentication-controller-mixin';`